# Page Builder not working after composer installation on Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2.4, page-builder

I installed PageBuilder on my Magento 2.4.2 application using composer:

```
composer require magento/module-page-builder
```

However, the pagebuilder is not working. I can see this in the logs:

```
[2022-06-22 11:17:28] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/jquery/z-index.js' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:17:28] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/jquery/z-index.js' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:20] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/stage-builder.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:20] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/stage-builder.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:20] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/config.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:20] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/config.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:20] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type-factory.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:20] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type-factory.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:20] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/appearance-config.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:20] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/appearance-config.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:20] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type-collection.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:20] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type-collection.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:20] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/style-registry.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:20] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/style-registry.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:20] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/master-format/validator.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:20] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/master-format/validator.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:20] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/loader.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:20] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/loader.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/object.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/directives.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/object.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/directives.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/collection.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/collection.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/string.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/string.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/master-factory.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/master-factory.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/preview-factory.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/preview-factory.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/data-store.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/data-store.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/converter-resolver.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/converter-resolver.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/array.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/array.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/page-builder.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/page-builder.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/observable-updater-factory.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/observable-updater-factory.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/preview-converter-resolver.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/preview-converter-resolver.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/acl.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/acl.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/stage.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/stage.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/panel.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/panel.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/template-manager.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/template-manager.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/binding/style.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/binding/style.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/converter-pool-factory.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/converter-pool-factory.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/observable-updater.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/observable-updater.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/drag-drop/drop-indicators.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/drag-drop/drop-indicators.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/drag-drop/registry.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/drag-drop/registry.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/mass-converter/converter-pool-factory.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/mass-converter/converter-pool-factory.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/panel/menu.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/panel/menu.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/binding/draggable.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/binding/draggable.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/panel/menu/content-type.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/panel/menu/content-type.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/position-sticky.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/position-sticky.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/drag-drop/matrix.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/drag-drop/matrix.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/editor.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/editor.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/promise-deferred.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/binding/sortable.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/promise-deferred.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/binding/sortable.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/master-format/render.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/master-format/render.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/converter-pool.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/converter-pool.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/observable-updater/css.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/observable-updater/css.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/observable-updater/attributes.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/observable-updater/attributes.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/observable-updater/style.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/observable-updater/style.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/mass-converter/converter-pool.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/mass-converter/converter-pool.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/observable-updater/html.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/observable-updater/html.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/create-stylesheet.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/create-stylesheet.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/master-format/render/serialize.js.map' [] []
[2022-06-22 11:23:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/master-format/render/serialize.js.map' [] []
```

And also this in console:

[image]

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful to you, as I had a very similar issue recently.

Basically, a bunch of my jquery requires were 404'ing.

It turns out when I upgraded from 2.4.3 > 2.4.5, I didn't update the `/lib` directory. This handles all jQuery related code.

Even though you probably fixed it already, I'm hoping this helps someone who is also bereft of ideas.

Thanks